# AR.js multiple markers failure

Tags: javascript, ar.js

I'm using 2 custom patterns and trying to make AR.js recognize them. both of the markers are 6x6 barcodes that I've made into pattern using [AR.js Marker Training](https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/three.js/examples/marker-training/examples/generator.html), and put the downloaded pattens into the folder (as 500.patt and 600.patt). The result is both markers identified when I show it a single marker as showed in picture.

In addition, I would like to get a reaction when a marker is recognized (that's why the console prints are there), but although both markers' shapes are drawn, there are no prints in the console.

My code:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ar.js</title>

</head>
<!-- include A-Frame obviously -->
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<!-- include ar.js for A-Frame -->
<script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
  <a-scene embedded arjs="patternRatio: 0.90">
    <!-- create your content here. just a box for now -->
    <!-- define a camera which will move according to the marker position -->
    <a-marker-camera type='pattern' url='500.patt'>
        <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='opacity: 0.5; color: red;'></a-box>
        console.log(500);
    </a-marker-camera>
    <a-marker-camera type='pattern' url='600.patt'>
        <a-sphere position='0 0.5 0' material='opacity: 0.5; color: blue;'></a-sphere>
        console.log(600);
    </a-marker-camera>
  </a-scene>
</body>
</html>`
```

Outcome:
[image: bugs]

How do I make the pattern recognition show only one item and print the correct pattern recognized?

Thanks

Comment: I can only answer one of your two questions for now, see below. If this works for you, best edit your question to only ask for how to log something when a marker is triggered, and move the other part to a new question and then only ask for how to debug and fix the duplicate triggering with the wrong marker. (Please also accept the answer and leave a comment with a link to your new question, then I can take a look.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to log something to the console when a marker is recognized:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('registerevents', {
    init: function () {
        var marker = this.el;
        marker.addEventListener('markerFound', function() {
            var markerId = marker.id;
            console.log('! markerFound', markerId);
            // do additional things you want to do
        });
        marker.addEventListener('markerLost', function() {
            var markerId = marker.id;
            console.log('! markerLost', markerId);
            // do additional things you want to do
        });
    }
});
```

Then add the `registerevents` component to your marker:

```
<a-marker id="marker" preset='hiro' registerevents>
```

That should do it.